# How to tell flowtype about extending a partial options object, so it will be complete at a certain point

Tags: javascript, static-analysis, flowtype

A very simple usecase, that most of you will know from your projects.

You have a utility class/function or whatever that works like:

```
type Options = {
    foo?: string
};

class Something {

    static get defaultOptions(): Options {
        return {
            foo: "bar"
        };
    }

    options: Options;

    constructor(options: Options) {
        this.options = Object.assign({}, options, Something.defaultOptions);
    }

    toString(): string {
        return `some thing: ${this.options.foo}`;
    }
}
```

this is just an example with minimum complexity, but you get the point - in the toString method i can be sure, that options.foo is available and will be a string.

But flow complains because it acts like it is smart enough to understand the call stack but it is not, it does not take the Object.assign statement into account.

So how do i solve this?

I would like to avoid:

- Adding getter methods for each option.
- Add a second type that is complete and concrete and used as hint for the property

At this point i am not a big fan of flowtype :-/

**UPDATE**

So in that example case flow will throw something like this:

```
Cannot coerce this.options.foo to string because undefined [1] should not be coerced.

 [1] 13│     foo?: string,
       :
     47│     }
     48│
     49│     get toString(): string {
     50│         return `some thing: ${this.options.foo}`;
     51│     }
     52│
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$Shape` utility type. An example of how it works:

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number
};

type PersonShape = $Shape<Person>;
```

Now, `PersonShape` is equivalent to this object type:

```
type PersonShape = {
  name?: string,
  age?: number
};
```

With your example, instead of making `Options` have an optional property, just use `$Shape` in the only place where optional properties are expected. It would look like this:

```
type Options = {
  foo: string
};

class Something {
  static get defaultOptions(): $Shape<Options> {
    return {
      foo: "bar"
    };
  }

  options: Options;

  constructor(options: $Shape<Options>) {
    this.options = Object.assign({}, options, Something.defaultOptions);
  }

  toString(): string {
    return `some thing: ${this.options.foo}`;
  }
}

const thing = new Something({})
```

And here is a link to [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCigDMkkAuKNYAJwRQHM8BfAbjzwGMAbAQzQwDKSALYRgACzr1cBSsB6IOUemKgATCER4BXLsDiJUaABQBKCgBIB4npAA8B5OgB8MwoWpjt1FG-eEScigAIgAjHmpg2UJWWSZ2QiR4JzQKRyM2WQ4jGm0OYCRqYyTDdEtrWwgHZKNnUz9CCQQ0ADoSlKxYUIArCHyWvjQEehRjHCYAGih2oymhUSaGFo0tXX0a9FM2GISoAoEaKTMKKloGBqhPYG9fAAM0EWhF+kscJtaZ9BbAplvtqHi8U4OT2knO2BQEAA7lB5mIwfQxkxTEA).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Have a look at the accepted answer, thats the way to go.

--

Managed to do it!

*working example*

```
type Options = {
    foo?: string
};

class Something {

    static get defaultOptions(): Object {
        return {
            foo: "bar"
        };
    }

    options: typeof Something.defaultOptions;

    constructor(options: Options) {
        this.options = Object.assign({}, options, Something.defaultOptions);
    }

    toString(): string {
        return `some thing: ${this.options.foo}`;
    }
}
```

That does feel like adopting my coding to flow but i am happy for the moment.

Comment: It passes flow but defeats the object of type checking.

Comment: Yes, thats what i thought, thank you for your edit in the other answer, i am going to use that utility type.